# How can I skip selecting a slicer item if is doesn't exist in my reference data (Pivot Table)

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I am trying to update/filter a pivot table and select the following values. (See example code)

```vb
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_State")
    .SlicerItems("Analysis").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("Development").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("Analysis_Complete").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("Submitted").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("(blank)").Selected = True
    .SlicerItems("Closed").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("Rejected").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("Resolved").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("Test").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("Verified").Selected = False
End With
```

However, sometimes the item "submitted" won't exist in the source data and returns invalid argument errors.

If the data doesn't exist, how can I skip over the line?

Thank you

Comment: You can precede the line with `On Error Resume Next` then follow it with `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: Edit: I figured out a solution with a bunch of loops, but this solution runs very slow.